# Neo4j aggregation depending on relationship property

Tags: neo4j, relationship, data-modeling, aggregation

I want to make a database where a :Person can rate a :Movie on a criteria.
I want the criterias to be dynamic :

*For instance John could rate Titanic 3.8/5 for the acting and 4/5 for the special effects.
Anna could rate Titanic 4/5 on acting and 5/5 on decor*

For now, my strategy is :

- two types of nodes :Person and :Movie
- a Relationship :Person -[:Rate {criteria: string, grade: float}]-> :Movie

My question is :
Is there a way to cypher query the ratings of a movie aggregating the the grades by criteria?

*This query on the movie Titanic should return something like:*

```
[ {criteria: acting, avg_m.grade : 3.9},{criteria: special effects, avg_m.grade : 4},{criteria: decor, avg_m.grade : 5}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Cypher's `avg` function. Assuming you want to have averages on a movie with a title of "abc":

```
MATCH (:Movie {title:'abc'})<-[r:Rate]-()
RETURN r.criteria as criteria, avg(r.grade) as avg_grade
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the name of the relationship instead of having a property indicating the criteria? E.g. `(:Person)-[:RATED_ACTING {rating:5}]->(:Movie)`, `(:Person)-[:RATED_SPECIAL_EFFECTS {rating:4}]->(:Movie)` etc.

Comment: Both make sense, your variant will be faster nicole but if you have to access properties anyway (rating) then it won't make such a difference, and the query is easier to read/write for criteria as property.

Comment: Nicole solution can actually work but I want the criterias to be dynamic (generated by users) : how will I be able to query on relation of which I don't know the type?

Comment: since you cannot parameterize relationship types, I guess you'd be better off using generic `Rate` relationships and qualify them by `criteria` property.